# Почему после деплоя файл по ссылке стал открываться в браузере вместо скачивания?

Tags: html, vue.js, nginx, heroku, github-pages

Есть 3 ссылки для скачивания соответствующих файлов:

1. localhost/file/dictionary_ru/download
2. localhost/file/comments/download
3. localhost/file/info_categories/download

Которые после деплоя на сервер становятся соответственно:

1. https://bearings-info.herokuapp.com/file/dictionary_ru/download
2. https://bearings-info.herokuapp.com/file/comments/download
3. [https://bearings-info.herokuapp.com/file/info_categoкies/download](https://bearings-info.herokuapp.com/file/info_catego%D0%BAies/download)

На локалхосте все ссылки работают как требуется - файл скачивается.

В задеплоеном проекте - то же самое. За исключением 1 ссылки:

1. https://bearings-info.herokuapp.com/file/dictionary_ru/download

По ней после деплоя файл почему-то стал открываеться в браузере.

Почему на локалхосте скачивает, а на сервере открывает? Почему другие ссылки не ведут себя аналогичным образом? В чем разница?

**Проект:**

- localhost (все Ок - скачивается): Vue.js (фронт) + Spring Boot (бэк) + Nginx (обратный прокси)
- деплой (открывается вместо скачивания): фронт на GH Pages, бэк на Heroku, Nginx не используется

**Код:**

html:

```
<a :href="getDictionaryDownloadUrl()" download>
    {{"Download dictionary"}}
</a>

<a :href="getDownloadUrl('comments')" download>
    {{"Download comments"}}
</a>

<a :href="getDownloadUrl('info_categories')" download>
    {{"Download info categories"}}
</a>
```

js:

```
getDictionaryDownloadUrl() {
    let lang = this.$route.params.lang;
    return this.basicUrl + "/file/" + "dictionary" + "_" + lang + "/download";
},

getDownloadUrl(fileName) {
    return this.basicUrl + "/file/" + fileName + "/download";
}
```

**Можно посмотреть "вживую":**

old-vehicles.com/#/menu/ru -> "Скачать словарь"

И обнаружил еще одну особенность поведения: попробуйте переключить язык на польский и повторить "Download dictionary". Обратите внимание, что в этом случае словарь скачается.

Единственная разница межу всеми этими кейсами,которая мне приходит в голову, это то, что в файле dictionary_ru присутствует кириллица.

Answer (score 0):

Предоставите код ссылок типа: `<a href="#">Файл</a>`
Возможно нужно к ссылкам добавить атрибут для скачивания `<a href="#" download="">текст ссылки</a>`

Comment: Атрибут download в ссылках есть. Код ссылок добавил.

Comment: Можете предоставить код ссылок в браузере, инспекторе или в коде страницы?

Comment: Да, конечно. Думаю, наиболее информативно будет, если Вы увидите все "вживую": https://www.old-vehicles.com/#/menu/ru -> "Скачать словарь". После попробуйте переключить язык на польский и повторить "Download dictionary". Обратите внимание, что в этом случае словарь скачается.

Comment: Посмотрев на сайт, однозначного ответа не могу дать, попробуйте в польском вариант вставить текст с русского. Возможно всё таки проблема в кодировке.

Comment: Нет, не в кириллице дело. Опытным путем определил, что файл начинает открываться вместо скачивания как только начинает весить более 8.2kB. Только в задеплоеном проекте. На локалхосте продолжает скачиваться. Но при этом имя скачанного файла меняется c "dictionary_pl.txt"  на "download".